# Is there a way to set up a Ghost-type with Synchronize for SOS chaining?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon, pokemon-seventh-generation

I want to SOS chain a Beldum for a shiny, but Take Down is an issue. So naturally, I want a Ghost-type so it doesn't knock itself out. The issue is that I also need it to have Synchronize so that it's likely to be Adamant on my chaining Pokémon. I don't have access to Pokémon Bank, so that's a limitation, but if it's possible to do this through Pokémon Bank, I might get it.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is. Use the following method:

- Get an Adamant Smeargle, preferably a high-level one.
- Get a Staryu with Reflect Type, get a wild Smeargle to copy it, and copy it off of the Smeargle with your one.
- Teach it Sketch again at the move relearner.
- Get a Sylveon with Skill Swap and get a wild Smeargle to copy it, and copy it off of the Smeargle with your one.
- Teach Smeargle False Swipe and a good powerful move against Beldum with the above method. Single target only, no Normal or Fighting-types.
- Breed a male Reuniclus line Pokemon with Skill Swap with a female Ralts line Pokemon so you have a Ralts with Skill Swap and Synchronize, which you train up.
- Get a Pokemon with Trick-or-Treat, Gourgeist probably.

Now we chain:

- Trick-or-Treat Beldum with Gourgeist.
- Skill Swap it Synchronize with Gardevoir.
- Then you send in Smeargle who Reflects Type to become a Ghost-type then Skill Swaps to grab Synchronize.
- Get Beldum to call a friend with Adrenaline Orb.
- KO the Ghost-type Beldum, then chain with False swipe, switching Beldum after 15 turns each so it doesn't struggle after the 20th move

This works with Jangmo-o, Bewear and Riolu too, but they have different lengths of turns. The call rate is also different, and after a 255 long chain, there is only a 18% chance of a shiny throughout the whole thing. This is a long process, so get a lot of Leppa Berries. Synchronize still works despite swapping, but this is after 3 tests, of which an Adamant Smeargle has drawn 2 shiny Adamant Riolu.

Comment: This doesn't really solve the problem of the beldums struggling after their Take Down PP runs out. Doesn't that break the chain?

Comment: No. The allies summoned can continue the chain. The chain ends when all opposition is gone or the pokemon can no longer call for allies.

Comment: I don't think a Skill Swapped Synchronize works.

Comment: Beginning testing now, a total of 5 experiments, will report back number of times an Adamant nature occours

Comment: Just a note: Ralts and Pumpkaboo can't be found in Sun/Moon, and since OP doesn't have access to Pokebank he needs to obtain them in GTS or similar.

Comment: To avoid the need to trick or treat, you can use the first move slot as a powerful ghost type move (which is good for ko'ing beldums anyway), then use conversion instead of reflect type. Then you get false swipe and skill swap. If you don't have a better item, you can even z-conversion for a power boost.

Comment: As an aside, any friendly group online would help trade people these easy to obtain pokemon. I have these pokemon now, and the method works exceptionally well.

Answer (score 2):

An easier way that would solve your problem is to just use Heal Pulse instead. The Ralts line can learn Heal Pulse and have Synchronise.

There are other ways to solve this problem involving Magic Guard, Skill Swap, and Role Play, but if your goal is to stop the wild Beldum from knocking themselves out with Take Down or Struggle recoil while keeping Synchronise on your own Pokémon, simply using Heal Pulse is your best bet.

If you also want to prevent them from struggling, bring along a Pokémon with a leppa berry, recycle, and fling. Munchlax and the elemental monkeys can learn recycle and fling by level up. Then you can just keep flinging leppa berries at the beldum to restore their PP.

Comment: Wouldn't Fling kill them?

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer True, I forgot it did damage, though it would only be 10 base power with a berry.

Comment: 0+ Atk Ralts (level 50) Fling (10 BP) vs. 0 HP / 0 Def Beldum (level 25):   10-12 (16.1 - 19.3%) -- possible 6HKO

Comment: Unfortunately Recycle doesn't work with Bestow, otherwise that would be the better option.

Answer (score 0):

It's only possible through Pokebank if you have a Pokemon meeting the criteria you want in another game (compatible with PB) or in the bank itself.  You can't send yourself what you don't have.

Also I don't think Ghost types can have the Synchronize ability, and from checking online that seems to be the case.  You might be able to hack a ghost type to have that ability, but I don't have any experience of that. The only ones listed are:

- Abra
- Kadabra
- Alakazam
- Mew
- Natu
- Xatu
- Espeon
- Umbreon
- Ralts
- Kirlia
- Gardevoir
- Munna
- Musharna
- Elgyem
- Beheeyem

Source: [Bulbapedia Synchronize Ability](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Synchronize_(Ability))

Comment: Yes, but I was thinking along the lines of using something like camouflage to change types to ghost on syncronize pokemon or using ability moving tricks to change a ghost's ability to synchronize

Comment: @ThatOneRandomScrub The move "Trick or Treat" adds ghost typing. but only Puckaboo gets that move. Something that might be a lot easier is using Disable

Comment: @Taacoo That will force the beldum to struggle and thus KO itself even faster.